# Does this.(x) just get the value?

Tags: axapta, x++

Can someone explain what `this.(x)` denote, The `x` is already in the this object.

```
if (!this.(x))
{
    ok = checkFailed(strfmt("@SYS54774",fieldid2pname(this.TableId, x)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check a field on table using the field id on table in that way.
In your example you're accesing the field that has x as fieldNum.
For example, 1 is the fieldid of SalesId on salesTable, so you can set SalesId like this:

```
SalesTable salesTable;
int x = 1;
salesTable.(x) = 'a sales  id';
```

Comment: Of cause you would never hardcode field numbers, the compiler can do it for you: `int x = fieldNum(SalesTable,SalesId);`

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. Also you could receive x as a parameter in a function, or maybe you are looping through the table's fields. But you're right never hardcode a fieldnum